# How can I import generated QR code to SE78 by code?

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

Can we upload the generated QR code to `se78` by code?

I write this code to create QR code. How can I upload it to `se78` graphics other than manually?

```
CALL METHOD cl_rstx_barcode_renderer=>qr_code
EXPORTING
i_module_size = 120
* i_mode = 'A'
i_error_correction = 'L'
* i_rotation = 0
i_barcode_text = lv_qrcode_link
IMPORTING
e_bitmap = lv_qrcode.

DATA(it_raw_data) = cl_bcs_convert=>xstring_to_solix( EXPORTING iv_xstring = lv_qrcode ).

lv_xstrlen = xstrlen( lv_qrcode ).

CALL FUNCTION 'RSFO_XSTRING_TO_MIME'
EXPORTING
c_xstring = lv_qrcode

i_length = lv_xstrlen
TABLES
c_t_mime = lv_mime.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: Hope you arent planning to generate a warehouse full of QR Codes/ Barcodes using this technique   ;)

Comment: There are blog posts and answers at sap.com which provide an ABAP program to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either copy the code in LSTXBITMAPSF05 form import_bitmap_bds.
Or just do an external perform.

```
METHOD EXTERNAL_PERFORM.
        data:     l_filename       type rlgrap-filename,
                  l_name           type stxbitmaps-tdname,
                  l_object         type stxbitmaps-tdobject,
                  l_id             type stxbitmaps-tdid,
                  l_btype          type stxbitmaps-tdbtype,
                 l_format         type c length 3,
                 l_title          type c length 64 ,
                 l_resident       type stxbitmaps-resident,
                 l_autoheight     type stxbitmaps-autoheight,
                 l_bmcomp         type stxbitmaps-bmcomp,
                 l_docid          type stxbitmaps-docid,
                 l_resolution     type stxbitmaps-resolution.


   l_filename   = 'C:\temp\toxic.bmp'.
   l_name       = 'TOXIC'.
   l_object     = 'GRAPHICS'.
   l_id         = 'BMAP'.
   l_btype      = 'BCOL'.
   l_format     = 'BMP'.
   l_title      = 'This is the a toxic Bitmap'.
   l_resident   = ''.
   l_autoheight = 'X'.
   l_bmcomp     = 'X'.


     perform  import_bitmap_bds IN PROGRAM SAPLSTXBITMAPS
                                 using    l_filename       "filename
                                          l_name   " name of Entry  DEMO
                                          l_object "  GRAPHICS
                                          l_id     " BMAP
                                          l_btype  "BCOL   if its color
                                          l_format "BMP
                                          l_title     " description of bitmap
                                          l_resident  " typically blank, 
                                          l_autoheight "X   , your call
                                          l_bmcomp    "X
                                 changing l_docid
                                          l_resolution.



  ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: I don't want to download or import from directory. I just want to create the QR code and directly import to se78.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: then copy the code inside import_bitmap_bds.
Instead of GUI_UPLOAD, replace with you code to generate QRCODE/barcode as xstring. The title did say "how can I upload...."  maybe fix the question

Comment: what will be the l_filename ?
I want to direct use the QR generated .
Whenever i directly use lv_qrcode or lv_mime it is showing the error of invalid datatype?
Please guide me regarding this.

Comment: you replace the gui  upload which gets the binary data, with you generate Graphic code.
So that means copying import_bitmap_bds and adjusting for your purpose.

Comment: I am using "cl_igs_image_converter" but i am facing a issue "Cannot open file" file using execute method.
​Please suggest me any solution. Same question is asked but don't have any answer. 
​https://answers.sap.com/questions/13041512/cannot-open-file-error-when-trying-to-convert-jpeg.html